# Trying to use the Jint Engine with Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, jint

I want to experiment a bit with Jint on Monotouch and although the Jint-Mono project (not the monotouch version but the mono) works on my mac I am not able to get it to work for the iPhone. I just crated this class:

```
namespace iPhoneTests
{
    public class JintObject
    {
        public JintObject ()
        {
        var jintEngine = new JintEngine();
        jintEngine.Run
                    (
                    @"Console.WriteLine('Hello World')"
                    );

        }
    }
}
```

and whenever I try to call the JintObject method I get an Exception Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at Jint.Marshaller.WrapMethod (System.Reflection.MethodInfo info, Boolean passGlobal) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Jint.Native.NativeMethod..ctor (System.Reflection.MethodInfo info, Jint.Native.JsObject prototype, IGlobal global) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Jint.Native.NativeConstructor.ReflectOverload (ICollection`1 methods) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try with the new version which is a PCL https://github.com/sebastienros/jint https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint Announcement: https://jint.codeplex.com/discussions/536901

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to use Jint and Jurassic with MonoTouch in the past.

The problem I've always encountered is that both of those projects use Reflection.Emit in order to interpret the JavaScript - and that type of JIT operation is not supported on the phone. I suspect this is what you are seeing (look at the console output to see?)

The only solutions I found for this were:

- going back to an old version of Jint - I think 0.9 had no Reflection.Emit in it.
- abandoning a managed library and using the ios javascriptcore library instead - but to use this required a lot of bindings to be written

Comment: I am going to test it with an oldest version and I'm gonna let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Works perfect. The version without Reflection.Emit is 0.8.9.

Comment: I was hoping that 0.8.9 worked in Mono but Moma found 16 methods not implemented. :(